# i have a indentationerror in python

Tags: python, web-crawler, tweepy

```
 while(cnt<=10):
 ... tweets = api.search(keyword)
 File "<stdin>", line 2
 tweets = api.search(keyword)
      ^
 IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I don't know why this problem. plz hlep

Comment: Well.. clearly you need to fix your indentation. It's hard to say what's going on here, are the dots (`...`) a part of your source?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error pretty much says it all. Every line after `while(...):` you want to execute in this loop needs to start with a tab / four spaces.